# Create a text file in a dialog box

Tags: vb.net, winforms, text, dialog, savefiledialog

I want to save my data to a text file by clicking a button.
I  write on a existed text file by following code. It is very easy to use because of file.writeline function and I preffer this method:

```
    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("D:\test.txt", True)
    file.WriteLine("-------------'Input data'-------------")
```

But I need a code to create a text file and let the user select it's name. I want to open a save dialog box or something like this.
How could I do this?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Have you tried showing a `SaveFileDialog` and using the result? Just show it using `ShowDialog` and check if the result is `DialogResult.OK` then use the `FileName` as file name. Also use `System.IO.File.WriteAllText` to save the contents.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to create a text file because you mixed 'create' and 'existing' in your question.

You need something like following code but you have to change the code for your needs e.g. by adding a Save button to the form. Please note and try to change following line for your needs too:

> Dim fsOut As New FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Append)

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
  Private Sub btnOpen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpen.Click

    With OpenFileDialog1
      '.DefaultExt = "txt"
      '.FileName = "test"
      .Filter = "Textfile (*.txt)|*.txt"
      .CheckFileExists = True
      .InitialDirectory = "D:\"
      '.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
      '.Multiselect = False
      .Title = "Select text file"
    End With

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
      txtFilePathName.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

      Dim fsOut As New FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create)
      Dim swFile As New StreamWriter(fsOut)

      swFile.WriteLine("-------------'Input data'-------------")
      swFile.Close()
    End If

  End Sub
End Class
```

[image]